# Where is the "Use Storyboards" button in Xcode 8.3?

Tags: xcode

In older versions, it was a "Use Storyboards" button when creating a Cocoa app that determines whether to create a storyboard file or a xib one, but now I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Because it isn't there. It is superfluous. Just make your Cocoa project and get started. If you then want to make a *xib*, make one. If you want to make another *storyboard*, make one.

If you want to write an application that uses no storyboards at all but uses a main nib as in the old days, then make an Application *xib* file or a MainMenu *xib* file and point the target's Main Interface setting at it, and delete the default storyboard. (I just wrote an application that works that way, and it was no trouble at all. Just watch out because a modern *xib* has "Prefer coder" turned on by default, which may come as a surprise to an old AppKit fogie like myself.)